# average time for SURF(speeded-up robust features) implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, object, tracking

I have been implementing real-time object tracking for which I am using OpenSURF (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28300-opensurf--including-image-warp-) library in matlab.But the problem is to extract SURF features alone it is taking around 0.5 seconds for a single frame(I have tried for several times). This makes my real time implementation very slow. 
But people say that SURF is the fastest algorithm for feature extraction. Am I doing anything wrong here? or OpenSURF library implements it slow?
Or can I implement any other better algorithm for real-time object tracking?
any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What is the resolution of the your images?

Comment: well Matlab is around 100-1000 times slower than C/C++ for example, so what it is fast somewhere its not that fast elsewhere. I don't know if SURF is that fast in Matlab (I haven't tried it) but in openCV for C++ I can ensure its way faster than that. Are you sure the problem is not in using Matlab?

Comment: my image resolution is 640*480. but i tried with 320*240 also, no great improvement

Comment: I m sure because I m using the openSURF library as provided by mathworks itself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually look more info in the link you provided. The last comment (in the webpage) is someone complaining about the speed of the algorithm on 28 Jul 2010 because it takes 11s in the test image. The next day the OPupdates the code for a 10x speedup, so 1s. You are getting 0.5, so thats pretty fast!

Recommendation:

Dont SURF all images. SURF 1 out of 10-20 secs, and apply optical flow to track those points during frames. Each 10-20 images, SURF and match the feature points, to make sure you didn't loose any. If you do this in a parallel tread better!